# jquery ajax return with html result

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using jquery ajax to post username and password and return with a result it with working perfectly with GET method but using the post method it send the data but not return with the html result 
here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "panel.aspx",
    data: username + ";" + pw,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#midiv").html(result);

    }
});
```

Comment: Post your data using JSON map instead of your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'panel.aspx',
    data: {
          'username=' + uname "&password=" + pword,
//Note:- uname and pword are variables and not text
          },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#midiv").html(result);

    }
});
```

in your aspx, you may catch data something like;

```
Dim uname, pword
uname = Request.Form("username")
pword = Request.Form("password")
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "panel.aspx",
    data: {
        username: "foo",
        pw: "bar"
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#midiv").html(result);
    }
});
```

The way you are doing you are sending the variables in the GET request URL. To send data via post, define an object in the `data` config which the keys represent the parameters that you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the data correctly, try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "panel.aspx",
    data: 'username=' + username + "&password=" + pw,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#midiv").html(result);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "panel.aspx",
    data: {username: username, password: pw}
}).done(function(result) {
    $("#midiv").html(result);
});
```

You'll also need to change your serverside scripts to listen for POST requests and not GET requests, for instance in PHP it would be:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
```

Not really sure how to do it in aspx, but I'm guessing you'll figure that out ?